# Express.js - pdf2pic generated PNG image from PDFkit buffer stream comes out corrupted

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, express, pdf

I've created **Express.js** `HTTP server` that listens for `POST` request of body containing text. This text is then used by **PDFkit** library to generate PDF with the text as a body.

I'm not saving the PDF on machine but instead I am piping it to the stream.

Finally - once stream is finalized - the buffer is then passed to **pdf2pic** for conversion to PNG image. However after responding back to client and file is saved on client machine, it comes out corrupted (file size too small).

I've tried to debug and pinpoint the issue, but with no luck. Maybe the buffer is incomplete or prematurely sent?

Here is front-end (client) code of axios request (I'm using **FileSaver **`saveAs` function to save PNG image:

```js
const requestData = {
  text: gift.value.text,
};

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
};

axios.post('/png', JSON.stringify(requestData), config)
  .then(response => {
     const blob = new Blob([await res.data], { type: 'image/png' })
     await saveAs(blob, fileName)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors
    console.error(error);
  });
```

And here is my server-side code of Express.js POST request response with the PNG image:

```js
import type { Request, Response } from 'express'
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as stream from 'stream'
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'
import { fromBuffer } from 'pdf2pic'

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/png', bodyParser.json(), async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { text } = req.body

  if (!text) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Text is required in the request body' })
  }

  // Create a PDF document
  const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument()

  // Create a writable stream for the PDF content
  const pdfStream = new stream.Writable()
  const pdfBuffer: Buffer[] = []

  pdfStream._write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
    pdfBuffer.push(chunk)
    callback()
  }

  pdfStream.on('finish', async () => {
    const pdf2pic = fromBuffer(Buffer.concat(pdfBuffer), {
      density: 100,
      saveFilename: 'output',
      savePath: './',
      format: 'png',
      width: 600,
      height: 800
    })

    const result = await pdf2pic(1) // Convert the first page

    console.log(result)
    // Send the PNG image back to the client
    res.contentType('image/png')
    res.send(result)

    // Clean up the temporary files
    fs.unlinkSync('./')
  })

  pdfDoc.pipe(pdfStream)
  pdfDoc.text(text)
  pdfDoc.end()
})

export { router as services }
```

And here is a screenshot of the corrupt image file:

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

---

**[UPDATE #1]** - *Testing if PDF buffer stream returns working PDF file to client.*

So as per suggestion I double checked if PDF buffer stream is being returned correctly - and it does. Here is the code I updated to do the test:

```js
router.post('/png', bodyParser.json(), async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { text } = req.body

  if (!text) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Text is required in the request body' })
  }

  // Create a PDF document
  const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument()

  // Create a writable stream for the PDF content
  const pdfStream = new stream.Writable()
  const pdfBuffer: Buffer[] = []

  pdfStream._write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
    pdfBuffer.push(chunk)
    callback()
  }

  pdfStream.on('finish', async () => {
    // Set the content type to PDF
    res.contentType('application/pdf')

    // Send the PDF buffer directly to the response
    res.send(Buffer.concat(pdfBuffer))
  })

  pdfDoc.pipe(pdfStream)
  pdfDoc.text(text)
  pdfDoc.end()
})
```

Comment: have you tried to save the png in the server side and see if it is correct? then at least you know that is not the problem with the buffer contents but an issue of how you send back the response

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica I have similar POST request process but only for PDF, which comes out fine, however I'm piping it directly to response. I guess I'll try to replicate it closer to PNG call and see if I notice the issue.

Comment: @KJ As mentioned above, PDF buffer comes out fine. I honestly researched for days before posting here and nothing came up regarding incompatible types.. or my issue specifically. My guess is that there is either issue with my buffering logic or pdf2pic generation (axios and piped response seems fine).

Also - GS is installed and working just fine.

Comment: @KJ ok, so I updated my question with the test code - just PDF buffer stream is returned right and it works fine. Therefor I'm pretty sure it is the `pdf2pic` issue.

First of all thanks for the input - I think I will try another PDF to IMAGE library before tinkering with GS/ImageMagick downgrading. Honestly I'm okay with JPEG or TIFF formats as well, PNG was just an intuitive choice of format.